# Допустимо ли говорить "по вопросам курсов дополнительного образования, наберите 220"?

Tags: общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка

Или правильно "по вопросам о курсах дополнительного образования, наберите 220"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: "по вопросам (чего?)  курсов дополнительного образования. А не: "по вопросам (о чем) О курсах дополнительного образования, наберите

Answer (score 3):

Вряд ли можно "набрать номер по вопросам": нужно хотя бы пояснить, что даст набор этого номера. Например, "**для справки** по вопросам... наберите". Иначе такое предложение может показаться даже невежливым, мол, если по таким вопросам, то это не к нам - если что и есть, имеющее к этим вопросам отношение, то возможно, что по этому номеру.

Comment: @Alex_ander, согласен.Стилистически предложение построено неграмотно. . Но грамматически - верно. Даже не заметил слово "наберите".